# Glide ModelLoader that loads either from local or remote

Tags: android, android-image, android-glide

I have a custom Glide model to calculate the center crop for image. The same model is used for getting images from server and also from local storage.

Here's the model interface:

```
interface CenterCropImageInformation {
    fun getCenterCropUri(context: Context, @Px width: Int, @Px height: Int): Uri
}
```

And here is its ModelLoader that extends from `BaseGlideUrlLoader`:

```
class CenterCropImageInformationLoader private constructor(
    context: Context,
    concreteLoader: ModelLoader<GlideUrl, InputStream>,
    modelCache: ModelCache<CenterCropImageInformation, GlideUrl>?
) : BaseGlideUrlLoader<CenterCropImageInformation>(concreteLoader, modelCache) {
    private val applicationContext: Context = context.applicationContext

    override fun getUrl(
        model: CenterCropImageInformation, width: Int,
        height: Int, options: Options
    ): String {
        return model.getCenterCropUri(applicationContext, width, height).toString()
    }

    override fun handles(centerCropImageInformation: CenterCropImageInformation): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    /**
     * The default factory for [CenterCropImageInformation]s.
     */
    class Factory(
        private val applicationContext: Context,
        private val modelCache: ModelCache<CenterCropImageInformation, GlideUrl>?
    ) : ModelLoaderFactory<CenterCropImageInformation, InputStream> {

        override fun build(
            multiFactory: MultiModelLoaderFactory
        ): ModelLoader<CenterCropImageInformation, InputStream> {
            val modelLoader = multiFactory.build(GlideUrl::class.java, InputStream::class.java)
            return CenterCropImageInformationLoader(applicationContext, modelLoader, modelCache)
        }

        override fun teardown() {}
    }
}
```

This works fine for images with `http/https` scheme, but it doesn't work for `file` scheme - the one used for loading images from local device storage.

I had a look into Glide's source code and the closest ModelLoader that sounds like an option is `UriLoader`, but the issue that that one doesn't support custom models. It only supports `Uri`.

The optimal solution would be to use a pre-existing ModelLoader that is bundled with Glide, but unless I missed it, I couldn't find any that suits my needs. If that's really the case, how do I implement such ModelLoader?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out after reading [Glide's ModelLoaders tutorial](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/tut/custom-modelloader.html#delegating-to-another-modelloader). The key is by delegating the loading to a ModelLoader that knows how to handle `file` and `http/https` scheme.

What I had to do is to implement `ModelLoader` interface directly instead of extending `BaseGlideUrlLoader`. We already know that Glide's built-in `UriLoader` can handle both `file` and `http/https` scheme so we delegate to it. Now to get an instance of `UriLoader` we use the `MultiModelLoaderFactory` that is passed to our factory's `build` method. The default Glide configuration registers `UriLoader` for `Uri` + `InputStream` pair.

```
class CenterCropImageInformationLoader(
        private val modelLoader: ModelLoader<Uri, InputStream>,
        private val modelCache: ModelCache< CenterCropImageInformation, Uri>
    ) : ModelLoader<CenterCropImageInformation, InputStream> {
        override fun buildLoadData(
            model: CenterCropImageInformation,
            width: Int,
            height: Int,
            options: Options
        ): ModelLoader.LoadData<InputStream>? {
            val uri: Uri = modelCache.get(model, width, height) ?: model.getUri(model, width, height)
            modelCache.put(model, width, height, uri)
            return modelLoader.buildLoadData(uri, width, height, options)
        }

    override fun handles(model: CenterCropImageInformation): Boolean = true

    class Factory(
        private val applicationContext: Context,
        private val modelCache: ModelCache<CenterCropImageInformation, Uri>
    ) : ModelLoaderFactory<CenterCropImageInformation, InputStream> {

         override fun build(
             multiFactory: MultiModelLoaderFactory
         ): ModelLoader<CenterCropImageInformation, InputStream> {
             val modelLoader = multiFactory.build(Uri::class.java, InputStream::class.java)
             return CenterCropImageInformationLoader(applicationContext, modelLoader, modelCache)
         }

         override fun teardown() {}
     }
}
```

As we can see we no longer extend `BaseGlideUrlLoader`. Instead we implement `ModelLoader` interface and in `buildLoadData()` implementation we try to get the URI from cache (this is similar to what `BaseGlideUrlLoader` is doing) and then we call `buildLoadData()` on the `ModelLoader` that we passed to the constructor, which happens to be an instance of `UriLoader` as I mentioned earlier thanks to `MultiModelLoaderFactory`.

It's really surprising that this type of ModelLoader is not part of Glide built-in model loaders.

Comment: Thank you for posting the solution!